# add notification to To-do list in android?

Tags: android

what i wanna do is , have a notification to inform user about upcoming task which has been added to todo list EVEN without opening the todo app  . i have used BroadcastReceiver by the way , because i have read android check them to see if there is any message has received by them.
I know something is missing coz i have don everything in mainactivity.java so it would be done just by opening the app.

here is my BroadcastReceiver file
public class Broadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String message = bundle.getString("alarm_message");
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    Toast.makeText(context, "received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

}

and here is my mainactivity.java

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
public NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
public NotificationManager notificationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // NOTIFICATION

    AlarmManager alarmMang = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    // ---get current date and time---

    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    calender.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);


    Intent noteIntent = new Intent(this, Broadcast.class);
    PendingIntent pendI = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, noteIntent, 0);
    long fireTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Notifications Example")
            .setContentText("This is a test notification");

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // // BUTTON NOT
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
        }
    });

    // // AET ALARM



    Toast.makeText(this, "lilili", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    alarmMang.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calender.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendI);


    notificationManager.notify(2332323, builder.build());
    // finish();

}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What have your read?  What specifically did the documentation not address?  The more specific your question, the more likely you are to get help here.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: Show a basic notification is relatively simple, this sample code can help you to understand how it works

```
// Notification.Builder is used to create the notification
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
// This set the title of the notification
builder.setContentTitle("Title")
// This set the content of the notification (the text inside the notification)
.setContentText("Content of the notification")
// Here you set the icon of the notification
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_copy);

// Build the notification and save it
Notification notification = builder.build();
// To show the notification you need to use the NotificationManager, to get it you should use getSystemService
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// .. then you can use .notify to show the notification
// 0 is the ID of the notification, you can use this ID to update the notification later.
// notification is the notification to show (you can use builder.build() inside too.)
manager.notify(0, notification);
```

But if you need more info about notification you **should** read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html), it's a very nice tutorial and explain everything with images too.